# Topology Circluar Quads

Tags: modeling, faces, edges, topology

I can't seem to wrap my head around on how to make a cricle from a square in a nondestructive way.

The result I'm trying to achieve is this:
[image]

Starting from this:

[image]

I've tried inserting a face but it won't let me slide it anywhere from it's starting point. I've also tried extruding and then scaling it in but the shading gets all weird. I just want to add the extra edges and make it more like a circle.

Any help would be appricated!

Comment: Use *Inset* and *Smooth Vertex* operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Inset* the faces with <kbd>I</kbd>, then use *To Sphere* tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>) to make the edge loops round.
[image]

Next enable the *proportional editing* (with a *Sphere* falloff type) and transform the middle vertex upwards (<kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>). Finally extrude the four middle faces upwards (<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>).
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Spin a subdivided section around its vertex and deform the result if you like.

Ok, here you are

1. Ađd a plane
2. Delete its three edges
3. Subdivide the remaining edge as many times as you want
4. Put the 3D cursor at one end of this edge
5. Select all and spin the edge with 3D cursor as your pivot

DONE

You may want to **UPVOTE** and **ACCEPT** it now.

Comment: Please add further details, steps and preferably screenshots, detailing *how* a user might do this.